# PHP preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

**strong text**i have a string like that "x", "x,y" , "x,y,h"
i want to user preg replace to remove the commas inside the double qutations and return the string as

**"x", "xy" , "xyh"**

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a regular replace.

```
$mystring = str_replace(",", "", $mystring);
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need `preg_replace()` here and whereever possible you should trying to avoid it

```
$string = str_replace(',', '', $string);
```

Comment: He does not want to remove all commas. Please read the question.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following, which I've found is generally faster than regexp for this type of replacement

```
$string = '"x", "x,y" , "x,y,h"';
$temp = explode('"',$string);
$i = true;
foreach($temp as &$value) {
    //  Only replace in alternating array entries, because these are the entries inside the quotes
    if ($i = !$i) {
        $value = str_replace(',', '', $value);
    }
}
unset($value);
//  Then rebuild the original string
$string = implode('"',$temp);
```

Comment: I am getting the opposite result: `"x" "x,y" "x,y,h"`.

Comment: @Michiel - In that case, change the initialisation of $i = false; to $i = true;

Answer (score 1):

This would work fine:  http://codepad.org/lq7I5wkd

```
<?php
$myStr = '"x", "x,y" , "x,y,h"';
$chunks = preg_split("/\"[\s]*[,][\s]*\"/", $myStr);
for($i=0;$i<count($chunks);$i++)
   $chunks[$i] = str_replace(",","",$chunks[$i]);
echo implode('","',$chunks);

?>
```